# Module 'soap' already loaded

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, soap

i am using plesk server and i am new to this server. i have created project in codeigniter when i upload the files to plesk server i got this error.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: Module 'soap' already loaded

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

since i have to much search on it but still i am not able to remove this bug anybody have solution about this? Have any php code or using .htaccess we can remove this bug?

Comment: You've probably loaded the soap extension in your php.ini file twice. Check your php.ini file.

Comment: thanks @Zander for comment i am little bit confuse how can i edit my php.ini file?

Comment: find a file called php.ini on your server & edit it using an editor. create a page that calls `phpinfo();` to see your php config, which will include the path to your php.ini file

Comment: @RobGudgeon the problem is i have no idea where is located php.ini file in my plesk server but i make a function to see phpinfo(); but still fail to find php.ini file

Comment: you should 2 entries in the output of phpinfo(): Configuration File (php.ini) Path => & Loaded Configuration File =>

Comment: What operating system is your server running?

Comment: @ZanderRootman my server is linux based

Comment: did you get any output from a call to phpinfo()?

Comment: yes i got output but i am not able to edit this output. my question is how can i edit this php.ini output

Comment: @MuhammadTalha check in: `/etc/php5/apache/php.ini` something like that.